# start full crawl is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

[image]I had config search in sharepoint 2013 but start full crawl is disable how can I fix it
[image]

Comment: Your SSA is paused. You can't start a crawl on a paused system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look if all services is started for sharepoint search in Central administration and task manager.

If all services is started try with this powershell

http://www.sharepointed.com/2013/07/08/paused-by-system/

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication “YOUR Search Service Application name here”

Resume-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $ssa
```

or with force

https://blog.vincenzonardone.it/how-to-resume-sharepoint-content-source-when-it-is-paused-by-system/

Resume SharePoint Content Source when it is “Paused by system”

```
#Connect to SharePoint FrontEnd Server
#Open SharePoint 2013 Management Shell

$SearchSA = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
$SearchSA.ForceResume($SearchSA.IsPaused())
```

Answer (score 0):

As per shared snapshots, search crawl is paused by System. use below code to resume it:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

Resume-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $ssa
```

**Force a index reset (if stuck):**

Make sure to reset the Search Host Controller service and timer service before running theses commands.

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

$disableAlerts = $true

$ignoreUnreachableServer = $true

$ssa.reset($disableAlerts, $ignoreUnreachableServer)
```